# Gradle 1.8 hangs on Resolving dependencies for Android but 1.6 get fine

Tags: android, gradle

I update my gradle from 1.6 to 1.8 to build my Android Apps. But no matter I use `gradle` or `gradle clean` the gradle would hang on `'> Loading > Resolving dependencies ':lib/actionbarsherlock:classpath''`
 
What's more, everything is right for gradle 1.6.
My build.gradle is below:

root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5+'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
        url "http://maven.oschina.net/content/groups/public"
    }
    }
}
```

setting.gradle:

```
include 'lib/library1'
include 'lib/actionbarsherlock'
include 'lib/library'
include 'qingdaobus160'
```

actionbarsherlock's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
        url "http://maven.oschina.net/content/groups/public"
    }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'
dependencies {
        compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    }
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest {
                srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
            java {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
            res {
                srcDir 'res'
            }
            assets {
                srcDir 'assets'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
            aidl {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the main project:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
            url "http://maven.oschina.net/content/groups/public"
           }
        }
        dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
        }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
        compileSdkVersion 18
        buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

        dependencies {
                compile project(":lib/actionbarsherlock")
                compile project(":lib/library")
                compile project(":lib/library1")
                compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        }


    sourceSets {
    main {
    manifest {
    srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    java {
    srcDir 'src'
    }
    res {
    srcDir 'res'
    }   
    assets {
    srcDir 'assets'
    }
    resources {
    srcDir 'src'
    }
    aidl {
    srcDir 'src'
    }
    }

    }
}
tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
   from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so' )  into  'build/native-libs' 
}

tasks.withType(Compile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLibs }

clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyNativeLibs'

tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask -> 
     pkgTask.jniDir file('build/native-libs') 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your issue you have to update this part:

```
dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
        }
```

to

```
dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
        }
```

because Gradle 1.8 requires 0.6.3.

Then you have to modify the settings.gradle in:

```
include ':lib:library1'
include ':lib:actionbarsherlock'
include ':lib:library'
include ':qingdaobus160'
```

and you should have this structure:

```
root
 - qingdaobus160
     build.gradle 
 - lib
   - library  
        build.gradle
   - library1
        build.gradle
   - actionbarsherlock
        build.gradle
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

and you have to modify the qingdaobus160/build.gradle in:

```
dependencies {
                compile project(":lib:actionbarsherlock")
                compile project(":lib:library")
                compile project(":lib:library1")
                compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        }
```

To improve the project, I suggest you to change

```
dependencies {        

      compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    }
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
```

or

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
```

Finally you can use sherlock action bar in aar format, instead of a local library.
Change

```
compile project(":lib/actionbarsherlock")
```

with

```
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

You can remove your local abs library, and `include 'lib/actionbarsherlock'` from your settings.gradle